# Function returning nothing when it should return char

Tags: java, arrays, char

In the program I'm writing I have a class called `Map` and within that class is a function called `coord`, which returns the map coordinate of the given point.

`Map` class definition:

```
public class Map
{
    public static char map[][] = new char[150][150];

    public static char coord(Point locat)
    {
            if ((locat.v <= 0) || (locat.h <= 0))
                    return '\u0000';
            return map[locat.v-1][locat.h-1];
    }

    public static int readToArray(String filePath)
    {
            try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                 BufferedReader from = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
                    int c, h, v;
                    h = v = 0;

                    while ((c = from.read()) != -1) {
                        if (c == '\n') {
                            v++;
                            h = 0;
                        } else {
                            map[v][h++] = (char) c;
                        }
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return v;

             } catch (IOException x) {
                    System.err.println(x);
             }
             return -1;
    }
    /* blah blah blah */
}
```

`Point` class definition:

```
public class Point
{
    public int h, v;
    /* blah blah blah */
}
```

The `Map` class is static. My `main` function calls `readToArray`.

I added `printf`s to find that the `coord` function passes the error check but the `char` returned is empty. Why is this and what should I do to change it?

Comment: How can you expect someone else to reproduce this? 1) We have no idea what is in the input file and thus going into the char [] [] array, 2) You don't give us the main method that calls readToArray. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: **NEVER** name your class *Map*

Answer (score 0):

Your function to retrieve values from the array returns `\u0000` if the indices are bad. That `char`, I believe, displays nothing when printed, not even a space. Thus it IS printing a `char`, just one that doesn't actually mean anything gets displayed.